# How to Port customField PHP from Drupal 6 Views 2 to Drupal 7 Views 3

Tags: views, entities

I have this piece of code that was in a Drupal 6 Views 2 customField PHP that I need to port to Drupal 7 Views 3 in a Global: PHP field but I can't figure why I get an empty ajax error upon building this code in the Global: PHP field value code.

Did the accessibles variables changed?

```
<?php
//var_dump($data);
if ($data->node_type=="project") {
echo "node/".$data->nid;
}
else
{
echo $data->node_data_field_slider_include_field_slider_link_value;
}
?>
```

**ANSWER**

You need to remove the `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: Hi, welcome to DA! :) Please, post your answer as an actual answer below, so the question can be marked as answered, or it's gonna litter the unanswered queue for no particular reason. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `<?php ?>` tags.